# jQuery bind images with dropdown in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to show image in the dropdown using asp.net c#, I got the following example working but it works on page which dont have a a master page.

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/12/jquery-bind-images-to-dropdownlist-in.html

I need the same drop down with images on a master page. right now it binds to the database and get the value but for some reason doesnt work on page which use masterpage

Partial code of master page

```
<%@ Page Title="Website Administration : Add New Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="SiteAdmin.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="AddNewPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="CKEditor.NET" Namespace="CKEditor.NET" TagPrefix="CKEditor" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <link href="../dropdown/dd.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../dropdown/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../dropdown/js/jquery.dd.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        try {
            $("#ddBanner").msDropDown();
        } catch (e) {
            alert(e.message);
        }
    });
</script>


<table><tr><td>

    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddBanner" runat="server" Width="424px">
</asp:DropDownList>

</td></tr></table>
```

I cross check path and everything but does not work.. for some reason

Comment: it has nothing to do with the master pages, only thing which u need to check is the path for your jQuery files does it execute properly???

Comment: @Murtaza, I cross checked path several time. It works on test.aspx page (i don't use master page for this one) and Test2.aspx which uses master page and it doesn't works. I have even copy paste working and both file test.aspx and test2.aspx are in the root folder so i dont thing it has path problem. Test2.aspx page get the same html code fill teh dropdown with value and image path but doesnt show the image. So i am really confused where things are goind wrong.

Comment: @Murtaza, code in this example is in a sub folder but i have tried a test file on root folder.. also

Comment: refer to the answer posted below by @Nicolai.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ddBanner list, is not called ddBanner, when in a contentPlaceHolder. The rendered page, will have the placeholder's name, prefix the dropdown. If you goto your rendered page, and show the source, you will see this.
You need to insert its clientID instead, or type the full name, from the rendered page.

```
$("#ddBanner").msDropDown();
```

should be

```
$("#<%= ddBanner.ClientID %>").msDropDown();
```